# Changing text colour of Html (H2) tag while mouseover in any picture?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my text on picture to be changed while mouse is on picture, in the code below my text color changes just when i have mouseover in the text.

Html :

```
   <div class="mnrImage" style="text-align: center; width: 183px">
   <a href="a.com" onmouseover="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" onmouseout="image1.src=staticImage1.src;">
   <img name="image1" src="./goal/images/normalButton.png"  style="vertical-align: middle; width : 183px;"/> 
   <h2 class ="mnrImageH2"><span class = "mnrImageSpan">Haberler</span></h2></a>
   </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
<script>
loadImage1 = new Image();
loadImage1.src="./goal/images/clickedButton.png";
staticImage1 = new Image();
staticImage1.src="./goal/images/normalButton.png";
</script>
```

CSS :

```
.mnrImage{ position: relative;  width: 100%;}
.mnrImage:hover{ position: relative;  width: 100%; text-color:black}
.mnrImageH2{ position: absolute;  top:1px;  left: 0;  width: 100%; }
.mnrImageSpan{ color: white;  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;  letter-spacing: -1px;  padding: 10px; }
.mnrImageSpan:hover{ color: black;  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;  letter-spacing: -1px;  padding: 10px; }
```

Comment: You need a simple script for this. You put jquery-tag to your post, do you mean to use it or pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just using CSS:

### HTML:

```
<img name="image1" src="./goal/images/normalButton.png" style="vertical-align: middle; width : 183px;" />

<h2 class="mnrImageH2"><span class = "mnrImageSpan">Haberler</span></h2>
```

### CSS:

```
.mnrImageH2 {
    position: absolute;
    top:1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.mnrImageSpan {
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    padding: 10px;
}
h2 {
    color: white;
}
img:hover + h2 {
    color: #000;
}
```

So using the `+` selector we can select the `h2` when we hover over an `img`.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/TGJGU/)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the text colour of any h2 tag whilst mousing over any picture like this:

```
$("img").on("mouseover", function(){
   $("h2").addClass("red"); 
})
.on("mouseout", function(){
   $("h2").removeClass("red"); 
});
```

If you just want to change a specific h2 tag then use a class:

e.g. `$("h2.myClass").addClass("red");`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/yy8mJ/)

**EDIT**: You tagged your question jQuery, but you know you can do this with CSS, right?

Comment: I thougt that it cant be solved with css, i put tag jQuery too, now i removed that tag, thanks for your help @Jack Zelig:)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your CSS `div> a:hover > h2 > span {color:green}`

```
    .mnrImage{ position: relative;  width: 100%;}
    .mnrImage:hover{ position: relative;  width: 100%; text-color:black}
    .mnrImageH2{ position: absolute;  top:1px;  left: 0;  width: 100%; }
    .mnrImageSpan{ color: white;  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;  letter-spacing: -1px;  padding: 10px; }
    .mnrImageSpan:hover{ color: black;  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;  letter-spacing: -1px;  padding: 10px; }
/*add this line*/
    div> a:hover > h2 > span {color:green}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your image source as well as the h2 text color on hover of the image, you can use this below code:

```
$('.mnrImage img').hover(function() {
    var h2Text = $(this).next().children(),
        name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).attr('src', "newImgSrc.jpg");
    h2Text.css('color','red');
    $(this).data('h2Text',h2Text);  
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', "./goal/images/normalButton.png")
    $(this).data('h2Text').css('color','blue');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A4aDn/)**